# How to resolve double percents in batch variable?

Tags: batch-file

I'm getting a value from the registry which has this string of data: `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
If i manually put `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop` it'd correctly perform `cd C:\Users\Name\Desktop`
But when i read the data from the registry, it gives `set DESKTOP = %%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop`

So if i do `cd %DESKTOP%` (`cd %%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop`) it performs `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
Which gives the error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

How can i resolve/evaluate the `%%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop` string data? (so `%%USERPROFILE%%` becomes `C:\Users\Name`)

Also this is how i get the data from the registry:
`for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop') do set DESKTOP=%%b`

Comment: In DESKTOP is only `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`, no double perecents, tested with `set desktop`

Comment: @jeb Run `cd %DESKTOP%` (don't forget to `pause` after) It'll try `cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop` as a literal address. For us to replicate that, we'd write `cd %%USERPROFILE%%\Desktop`. (the output shows only single percents)

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong. You see the literal address `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` not because DESKTOP contains double percents, but using percent expansion the content will not be expanded a second time.

Comment: @jeb Yeah i should've been more clear. It's similar to escape characters in python, you have to put 2 backslashes for it to know it's a backslash. `len("\\") = 1`

Comment: That's because all of those keys are of type REG_EXPAND_SZ, (they should by definition use variables requiring expansion). **1.** ```For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1,2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /V "Desktop" 2^>NUL') Do Call Set "%%G=%%I"```, **2.** ```Echo(%Desktop%```.

Comment: @Compo what do you use the `EOL=H` for?

Comment: It omits any output where `H` is at the beginning `E`nd `O`f the `L`ine. That in this case means the first line, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`. It then only has to perform the `Do` once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `CALL` command to evaluate an expression a second time.

```
echo %desktop%
call echo %desktop%
```

The `CALL` also works with other commands like `SET`, but not in front of `IF` or `FOR`